# Lower bound on the number of faces of a polyhedron of genus g

Tags: polyhedra

Is there a lower bound on the number of faces of a polyhedron of topological genus g?

For example: it seems very reasonable that $g$ < $F$ 
i.e. the genus of a polehydron is less than the number of faces of the polyhedron, but i can't find a proof.

To be clear what is meant by polyhedron let's use the definition from wikipedia:
"A polyhedron is a solid in three dimensions with flat polygonal faces, straight edges and sharp corners or vertices."

The genus can be calculated by $g = \frac{2-\chi}{2}$, where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic of the polyhedron.

Comment: And just to be clear, polyhedron means you're wondering about three-dimensional things, right?

Comment: Yeah that is what i meant. I should have been more precise

Comment: Do you want the faces to be convex, connected polygons?

Comment: I guess the most natural definition is connected, but not necessarily convex.

Comment: @WardBeullens More importantly than convex, do you require them to be contractible? (I.e., can they have "holes" in them?)

Comment: No, they don't have to be simply connected.

Comment: You make a good point with your $\frac{F(g)}{g}\le\frac{5}{2}$ as $g\to\infty$. Anyway, I deleted my answer as it didn't answer your question. I think I have an argument to attack the problem (using homology), but it doesn't work if you don't require the faces to be contractible.

Comment: What lower bound did you get (or do you think you can get) if you require the faces to be contractible?

Comment: @WardBeullens I think a bound of $g$ should be expected, and depending on your precise definition of polyhedron (e.g. do you require it to be a deformation of a smooth surface?) I think that working smartly you should get up to something as $2g$ or $3g$, maybe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of polyhedron with 4096 faces and 4097 holes.

P. McMullen, C. Schulz, and J.M. Wills. "Polyhedral manifolds in E3 with unusually large genus". Israel Journal of Mathematics., 46 (1983), no. 1-2, pages 127–144

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02760627

Comment: Wow, I did not expect that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The genus of an orientable surface represents the number of tori in a connected sum decomposition of the surface ($g=$ the number of "holes" in a closed surface). A polyhedron with $g>0$ is a toroidal polyhedron.

Let $F_i$ represent the initial number of faces of a polyhedron with $g=0$ that we will manipulate. A polyhedron must have a minimum of $4$ faces (tetrahedron).
$$ F_i \ge 4 $$
Let $F_h$ represent the number of faces added to our polyhedron when we add a hole to it. A polygon must have a minimum of $3$ edges (triangle), thus a minimum of $3$ faces are created by adding a hole in a polyhedron. Because $g=$ the number of holes,
$$ F_h \ge 3g $$
The sum of the initial faces and the faces added per hole gives the total faces:
$$ F = F_i + F_h $$
$$ F \ge 4 + 3g $$
$$ F > 3g $$
$$ F > g $$

Comment: This is not a valid proof, rather a heuristic.  And an incorrect one. The problem is that 'holes' can share sides. Indeed, there is an example of a genus 3 polyhedron with 12 faces

Comment: What do you mean by "'holes' can share sides"? Can you cite your example of $g=3,F=12$?

Comment: Sure, i will type it out in a few hours when i am home.

Comment: Thanks. I have been researching this question for a few days now. I suppose it is possible that I oversimplified a complex problem.

Comment: Suppose you have a tetrahedron, and you cut out 2 triangular tubes. Then you have a genus 2 manifold with 4+3*2 faces. So far your inequality holds. Now imagine that you move one of the tubes such that one of the faces of one tube overlaps with a face of the other tube. In this way you split to faces in 2 parts, so you get 2 extra faces. That makes 12 faces in total. But one can see that the resulting polyhedron has genus 3.

Comment: I follow you, but I am not sure I agree that the shape you just described has genus 3. Can't you continuously deform that shape into a double toroidal polyhedron? If so, it should have genus 2. I am having trouble calculating the genus by counting V, E, and F. Could this have to do with the 4 edges that each join 4 faces? Does the formula hold for such polyhedra?

Comment: I am quite sure that you can deform this into something which obviously has 3 holes. The formula for the euler characteristic only holds if all the faces are homeomorphic to disks, so you should add some vertices and edges in order to split those faces that are not homeomorphic to disks if you want to take this approach.

Comment: If I counted correctly there are 20 vertices, 32 edges and 12 faces, but you have to add 4 edges in order to make the faces homeomorphic to disks, so in total $\chi = 20-36+12 = -4$, so $g = \frac{2+4}{2} = 3$

Comment: I do not have the expertise to confirm or deny that count, because the edges confuse me. Perhaps this holey tetrahedron should be the subject of another forum question. I have a feeling that proving $F>g$ will require special restrictions on the type of polyhedron. On that note, we should try to find counter examples (a case where $F \le g$)... even extreme ones may provide valuable information

Comment: Im quite confident about the count. Especially because it confirms $g=3$, which i already 'knew' from a mental deformation of the surface.

Comment: You are right! I just had a topological epiphany... In my mental deformation, I was overlooking a sneaky handle. Thank you for the lesson.